# How to extract location form twitter user locations?

Tags: python, twitter, geolocation, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm using python tweepy package to extract covid-19 related tweets, and I need to pre-process the data, as you can see in the picture the user_location is not clear, I need to extract countries form this so there would be a column that indicates the country like India, United States, France, etc.
[Here is my Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5SUh.png)
I'm using the code on this page to get the data https://github.com/gabrielpreda/covid-19-tweets/blob/master/covid-19-tweets.ipynb

since the data is really diverse and patternless, one solution could be checking form a database or such thing to map attributes to a country but it would not work for all the cases and it would have a significant computational cost

Comment: It looks like the `user_location` contains an arbitrary string provided by the user, so there's no definitive way to determine the location. Other than that, for cities and other geographical names you need a database mapping these location names on countries and, on top of that, I would search for a library that does name comparison considering common spelling errors.

Comment: actually, I figured that out, but it is going to be computationally expensive and the result is not going to be as well as we expect because there are alot of wierd locations in the data, @bjhend any suggestion on getting the country location from twitter instead of this data ?

Comment: You should add these info to the question itself as "what I've already tried" and make more explicit that you want to read the location directly from twitter. Note, I'm only reviewing your question as experienced SO user, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: @bjhend thanks for your effort, yes I'll note that